# How can Overleaf handle \subfloat and subfigure environment together?

Tags: packages, subfloats, overleaf, subfig

I have written a paper in overleaf and used `\subfloat` and `subfigure environment` at the same time. I only included `\usepackage{subcaption}`. When I wanted to compile it on the local computer, it says: `undefined control sequence subfloat`. After I searched for this problem, found out that for using `\subfloat` I should include `subfig` package and it cannot be included with `subcaption` package at the same time. How overleaf handles this problem? I have used many times from `\subfloat` and `subfigure` environment? Is there any way I can compile the file on my computer?

Comment: It seems that *Overleaf* doesn't have installed recent version )(1.3) of the `subcaption` package. Ask *Overleaf* support to help you with installation of now already one year old version 1.3 (from 2020/08/24)  which support `\subfloat` as well `subfigure` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.3 (2019/08/31), the `subcaption` package also offers a `\subfloat` command. From the documentation:

[image]

Your local installation uses an older version of the `subcaption` package.

Comment: @luisturcio: As far as I understood, the OP successfully compiled a document using a combination of subfloat and subcaption on overleaf, but got the error message when trying to compile the same document on their local computer. Since it worked on overleaf, but not using the local installation, the latter must be the outdated one.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the original question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer